# cURL Request return weird value

Tags: php, curl

i tried this code to post something to form

```
$url_server = "http://insta.kingdompanel.xyz/addlikes.php";
                $postdata = array(
                    'url' => $url,
                    'comment' => $comment);
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500 );          
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url_server);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *','Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
                $output = curl_exec($ch);
                if ($output == FALSE){
                    echo "CURL ERROR".curl_error($ch);
                }
                curl_close($ch);
                print_r($output);
```

but it return something like this[image]
is it blocked? 
but i read something that website cannot block cURL request.
or i did something wrong? thank you

Comment: it's because if you run file directly also. you will get same response.check by running this in your browser directly:- http://insta.kingdompanel.xyz/addlikes.php

Comment: if i run it directly it doesnt show anything. have you try?

Comment: the link you given in your curl as URL when i run it directly through browser i get `( )( )=========D`

Comment: whoa, how can it be different? cause i get nothing when i run it directly through browser.... its real blank page